# Is there a more elegant way for checking a forms default values?

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for a better, cleaner and more elegant way to check for default values of a form using PHP.

As an example, say that this is my HTML (one of my form fields):

```
<input type="text" name="compName" value="Enter Business Name here (required)">
```

In the PHP side of things, say i have this variable that collects this fields data like so:

```
$compName = $_GET['compName']);
```

Now, lets say that the user left this field alone and didn't edit it, this then means that the variable "**compName**" is going to equal to "**Enter Business Name here (required)**".

Now, say I wanted to record this to a db or something and obviously I don't want to record the default value so I could do something like

```
if($compName == "Enter Business Name here (required)" ){
     $compName = "";
}

or


if($compName == "Enter Business Name here (required)" ){
     $compName = // make it some kind of default value etc
}
```

Now, imagine if I have 20 form fields each with their own default values, id have to write a lot of code, a lot of if/else statements to check for each form fields default values. This can get bloated and unruly quick!

Is there a function or anything that checks for an HTML forms default values? Like a catch all function?

For example, say this function existed and its called "$_MYCATCHALLFUNC()", then id still collect all the forms values into their respective variables like normal but then, i could do something like this

Example:

```
$variable1 = $_GET['value here'];
$variable2 = $_GET['value here'];
$variable3 = $_GET['value here'];

$allMyVarsToCheck = array($variable1, $variable2, $variable3);

foreach($allMyVarsToCheck as $varsChecked){
     if($_MYCATCHALLFUNC( $varsChecked ){
         //do something
     }
}
```

Is there anything like this available for PHP?

Comment: HTML5 `placeholder` & `required` + PHP [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) ?

Comment: @HAL9000 An old browser (or a hacker) can still send an empty parameter (or none at all).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel What do you mean by empty parameter ? I'm not suggesting to trust user input blindly.

Comment: @HAL9000 What did you mean with your comment, then?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I mean to leave the option, that permits to submition placeholder value to the server-side part and check if submitted value is empty only, then check for validity to business logic. Submition of a placeholders seems to be ugly... What if they remove just one character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on @HAL9000's comment, the best and more future-safe way to do it is to make use of new fields in HTML5:

To display the HTML, use the `placeholder` and the `required` attribute, like this

```
<input type="text" name="compName" value="" placeholder="Enter Business Name here (required)" required="true" />
```

In PHP code that receives the submit the field will be simply empty when the form is submitted without filling in the field (except when the browser supports the `required` attribute, [see here for an example](http://john.foliot.ca/required-inputs/), in that case it will prompt the user for filling out the field), so you can check it like this:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST["compName")) {
    // empty field handling
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a place holder to give information to user about that input field

```
<input type="text" name="compName" placeHolder="Enter Business Name here (required)">
```

and at PHP check if this field is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

You will repeat your self again and again.

```
/* 
 * Field name => field default value
 * If you have different languages on sites, you can use here function to translate
 * phrases like __()
 */
$defaultValues = array(
'compName' => __('Enter Business Name here (required)')
)

foreach($defaultValues as $filed => $value)
{
      if($_GET[$field] === $value)
      {
         $_GET[$field] = NULL;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, i would properly use some jQuery form validator on the html page, as this gives the user the possibility to correct the error before submitting to a new page. While we're at the HTML part of things, i would use the placeholder tag instead of value, as the placeholder text wont be sent with the form.

One simple way to check if users has inputtet something in the field wuld be use the function empty to check.

```
foreach($allMyVarsToCheck as $var){
 if(!empty($var)){
    return true;
 }else{
    return false;
 }
```